# I want to have location of other devices in my iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I understand that the mapkit is used to show a device location in the mapView , but I want to show the location of other ios devices in a map view of my application. Is there any options for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to maintain a web server with services running on it. One of the web service will accept the location details. From your app, at regular intervals, you have to post the location details to the server. Then with the help of other web service, you have to get the location details and show them in your app.